# Postgres on Linux, Need passwordless way of granting access to a table

Tags: postgresql, perl, dbi

PG 9.6.5 on RHEL6_64

Constraints I have to live with:

- I'm not a superuser, but I do have createrole.
- Password is required for login

Let's say I have a table called "approvals"...

```
create table approvals (approval_id text);
```

And another table called "granters"...

```
create table granters (linux_uid text);
```

I need a perl/DBI script that must allow all users select, but only those linux_uids in the "granters" table can insert/update/delete into the "approvals" table.  But when someone who is in the "granters" table runs the perl script, I do not want them to have to enter a password.  The perl script can validate that an authorized user is running it using 'getlogin' and that's good enough.

I can create roles for the granters and grant them select/insert/update/delete on the "approvals" table, but they'd have to enter a password to log in first (one of the constraints on the DB is that pawwsords are required).  So I can't see how this traditional method would work.

I could create before insert, update and delete triggers that can check the id of the person running the perl script against the list of uids in the "granters" table, then allow/reject the attempt on that basis.  But I can't pass the linux uid into the stored procedure associated with the trigger(s).  Something like perlplu might allow me to sniff out the linux uid, but again, I'm not a superuser, so (I believe) I can't create something like that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Users are authenticated *before* any permissions inside the database are checked, so you cannot do that just within the database. Also, since you need to do something outside the database, you need superuser privileges.

First, if I were you, I'd rethink that requirement. It looks complicated and cumbersome; there should be a better solution.

You could use `trust` or `ident` authentication for password-less authentication, but you cannot make that dependent on the contents of a table in the database. It is governed by the `pg_hba.conf` file.

So what you'd have to do is to create a trigger on the table that runs with superuser privileges through `SECURITY DEFINER` and edits (and reloads!) `pg_hba.conf` whenever the table is modified. This is complicated, error-prone and dangerous.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.  Ya, I came to the same conclusion, but was thinking someone else might have a way around this.  Some of these requirements are beyond my control.  Question:  Could the superuser author a procedure that leaves the DB, gets the linux_id and returns that as a string?  If so, then a before trigger could get the linux_uid, look for it in the "granters" table, and either permit or reject the change based on that.

Comment: The point is that you have to go through `pg_hba.conf` and find the authentication method *before you even connect*.